# solution and flow properties for autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Edit:** Lutz Lehmann's comment was useful and have amended the question to reflect this.

I wonder if anyone could help with the following that are related to representing the solution of the autonomous initial value problem $$\dot x = f ( x )$$ with the initial condition $ x ( 0 ) = X$.

If you introduce the solution in the form $$ x ( t ) = \varphi ( X, t )= \varphi ( x(0), t )$$ then it appears that the basic properties of the flow are

$$ (i) \quad \varphi ( x, 0 ) = x, $$
$$ (ii) \quad \varphi ( x, t + s ) = \varphi (\varphi ( x, t ), s ) = \varphi (\varphi ( x, s )), t ),  $$
$$ (iii) \quad d \; \varphi ( x, t ) / d \; t = f ( \varphi ( x, t ) ). $$

How does one go about showing $(ii)$? Presumably it follows that, because $t$ does not appear in $f ( x, \require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}t )$, you can replace $ t $ by $ t^\prime = t + s $ so that $ d t^\prime = d t$ and have $$ \frac{d x}{ d t } = f ( x ) \mbox{ gives }\frac{d x}{ d t^\prime } = f ( x )?$$

Comment: $x$ in $φ(x,t)$ is just a parameter, a vector from the state space. The flow function has the special property that $φ(x,0)=x$, that is, $φ(·,0)$ is the identity on the state space.